# Need to format table from BigQuery for specific words in the body of text

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I'm working with Google BigQuery to scrape the reddit comments database. I'll start with the query I'm working on:

```
SELECT
  DATE(SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(created_utc)) AS date,
  subreddit,
  author AS comment_author,
  ups AS upvotes,
  LOWER(body)
FROM
  [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2015_01]
WHERE
  body CONTAINS 'acid'
  OR body CONTAINS 'ecstasy'
  OR body CONTAINS 'fire'
  OR body CONTAINS 'heroin'
LIMIT 10;
```

I need to scrape the reddit database for a list of about 30 drug-related word (I limited it to 3 for brevity).

I'm having trouble with two things:

1. **I want to be able to correctly query the DB, but a lot of the results that are returned do not meet the criteria a.k.a. do not contain any of the matching words.**
2. **I want to be able to create a column which displays the specific word which was matched....so if it matched the word 'drug', that word would appear in a 'word_matched' column, along with the body, author, date, etc.**

I've tried regular expressions as well for matching the words, but that doesn't seem to be helping either:

```
  WHERE (REGEXP_MATCH(body,'drug|acid|ecstacy|fire|heroin|joint|marijuana|weed|bud|ganja|hash|blazing|blaze|meth|molly|pcp|shrooms|speed|uppers|valium|xanax|tripping|smoke|liquor|beer|alcohol|booze|acid|benzos|blow|cocaine|crack|crank|dank|dope|downers'))
```

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks all!

Comment: You may be getting results you do not want due to the way you have structured your REGEX. The | character indicates alternation. You are saying, find comments which return true when searched for the string drug OR acid OR ecstasy OR ... A comment discussing joint pain or a feeling of ecstasy will return TRUE for your REGEX.

Comment: @Nathan if that were the case I would be OK with the results. But I'm getting results that don't contain ANY of the words. Do you have any alternative methods you would recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below adressing both points of the question
1. Have in output only matching words and not those which are part of another/different word. This is easy to accomplish using [REGEXP_MATCH](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#regularexpressionfunctions)  function
2. Have column wich consists of all matching words. (i think it makes more sense to have all matching words vs. just one as it is asked in question.

```
SELECT
    [date],
    subreddit,
    comment_author,
    upvotes,
    GROUP_CONCAT(word) AS matches, 
    body
FROM (
  SELECT 
    [date],
    subreddit,
    comment_author,
    upvotes,
    body,
    word
  FROM (
    SELECT
      DATE(SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(created_utc)) AS [date],
      subreddit,
      author AS comment_author,
      ups AS upvotes,
      LOWER(body) AS body
    FROM
      [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2015_01]
    WHERE REGEXP_MATCH(body, r'\b(drug|ecstacy|fire|heroin|joint|marijuana|weed|bud|ganja|hash|blazing|blaze|meth|molly|pcp|shrooms|speed|uppers|valium|xanax|tripping|smoke|liquor|beer|alcohol|booze|acid|benzos|blow|cocaine|crack|crank|dank|dope|downers)\b')
  ) x 
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT SPLIT(list,'|') AS word FROM 
    (SELECT 'drug|ecstacy|fire|heroin|joint|marijuana|weed|bud|ganja|hash|blazing|blaze|meth|molly|pcp|shrooms|speed|uppers|valium|xanax|tripping|smoke|liquor|beer|alcohol|booze|acid|benzos|blow|cocaine|crack|crank|dank|dope|downers' AS list)
  ) y
  HAVING body CONTAINS word
)
GROUP BY [date], subreddit, comment_author, upvotes, body
LIMIT 1000
```

Above solution provides list of matching words on best-effort basis, so please note:
If column `matches` consists one word - it is for sure exact matched word
But if this columns consist of few words - still one of those is exact match, but others can be not exact match.
I think for lengthy body - it still valuable to have those at least as a hint to what to look for. For example as in

```
drug,meth,heroin,alcohol,benzos it also inhibits the reuptake of serotonin and norepinephrine which gives a hell of a lot worse withdrawal symptoms than most other drugs(incl. heroin, meth, coke and etc.). from what i have heard the only things that rival tramadol it terms of withdrawal are benzos and alcohol.
liquor,beer,alcohol,booze       1. reinforce #3 - it is not cheap to live here. not by any stretch. expect to pay more than the rest of the country pays for everything. even franchises that operate nation-wide have special wa/perth pricing. 2. petrol has literally just dropped to $1 this past month, i wouldn't go as far as quoting that as our average price just yet. average is still between $1.20-1.30. 3. parking is free at beaches &amp; parks, do not expect to get free parking anywhere in the city though. if you're using public parking in the city all day, expect to pay $50 unless you get in early. 4. forget bribing the cops, don't even call them "mate". last time i was pulled over (last week, random stop) i said "evening mate" as i was handing him my license and was responded with "don't call me mate, i'm not your friend, i don't know you". 5. unlike the rest of the world, regular stores do not sell alcohol here. liquor stores only, don't expect to buy beer from a gas station or grocery store. 6. rent is expensive, food is expensive, booze is expensive, being alive is expensive.
drug,meth,heroin,beer           that's simply not true. first there's a difference between legalization and decriminalization. second, some european countries have places to go to safely use drugs. there is middle ground between allowing heroin to be sold all over town and having users go to prison. heroin, meth and some other drugs are not good things for society and their use should encouraged by making it as easy to buy as a 6 pack of beer. i'm not really sure why you can't see a middle ground because it's clearly not as black and white as you say. you can go after the dealers while leaving the users alone.
drug,fire,joint,smoke           not a story about a rave, but still relevant i think: i was working a job called "fire watch," which is just what it sounds like, at a nine inch nails concert a few years ago. our comrades, the security workers, were far from seasoned professionals. they were mostly college temps with a yellow security tee shirt and a flashlight; they didn't even have radios. the job is basically to make sure people don't go into restricted areas. ...but this one boy scout took it upon himself to tame the metal masses. mid-concert, he pulled me close and shouted "they're smoking pot!" i shrugged, and shot him an "and?" look. i guess he thought i should care because technically a joint is a tiny dangerous drug fire, and i was on the fire crew. he then proceeded to disappear into the crowd, shoving people out of the way on his heroic journey toward the countless smoke puff origins. the next time i saw him he was bleeding out of his face and getting a flashlight in the eyes from an onsite emt. i guess it's pretty harsh to say that he deserved the beating, but it's hard to argue that he didn't go asking for it. i guess the moral of my story is that security people are just people, and some people's shittyness is inflamed when combined with authority. it sounds like your event just happened to be warded by a gaggle of douches, probably being captained by king fuckwad who really wanted to be a cop, but couldn't pass the exams.
```

Note: If you need list of only exact matches, it is still relatively easy to do with [BigQuery User-Defined Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions)

Comment: wow thank you! I just have one more question....If I wanted to add criteria to the search that include spaces.....such as "gettin high" or "shootin up", how would I achieve this? I tried plugging them in and im not getting anything back.

Comment: works for me - just add `|shootin up|gettin high` to the end of current list. But note: there are only 24 rows with those new two words - so you might not see them because of LIMIT 1000

Answer (score 2):

I suggest debugging this using `REGEXP_EXTRACT`.  I tried running your query, and it kept finding things like "meth" in "so**meth**ing", which might be what you're seeing.  You probably want to check for word boundaries around the match, since some of your words you are searching for can be contained in several normal, non-drug-related words.

Something like the following should help in debugging:

```
SELECT
  DATE(SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(created_utc)) AS date,
  subreddit,
  author AS comment_author,
  ups AS upvotes,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(body, '(drug|acid|ecstacy|fire|heroin|joint|marijuana|weed|bud|ganja|hash|blazing|blaze|meth|molly|pcp|shrooms|speed|uppers|valium|xanax|tripping|smoke|liquor|beer|alcohol|booze|acid|benzos|blow|cocaine|crack|crank|dank|dope|downers)') AS match,
  LOWER(body),      
FROM
  [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2015_01]
WHERE (REGEXP_MATCH(body,'drug|acid|ecstacy|fire|heroin|joint|marijuana|weed|bud|ganja|hash|blazing|blaze|meth|molly|pcp|shrooms|speed|uppers|valium|xanax|tripping|smoke|liquor|beer|alcohol|booze|acid|benzos|blow|cocaine|crack|crank|dank|dope|downers'))
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: thanks, that helped. I'm still having an issue with the "meth" concept. Word boundaries (\b) don't seem to be working with BigQuery. Do you know of a work around for this?

Comment: You either need a raw string with a single backslash (`r'\b(drug|foo)\b'`) or a non-raw string with double backslashes (`'\\b(drug|foo)\\b'`).  Both of those appear to be working for me.